# MySQL database function not working?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a database function like -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `lb2oz`(`lb` FLOAT) RETURNS float
BEGIN 
    DECLARE preLb FLOAT; 
    SET preLb = FORMAT(lb,0);
    RETURN preLb+ROUND(((lb - preLb)/16*100), 2);
END
```

When I call lb2oz(25.04) it return 25.25, it's ok.
But when I call lb2oz(25.01) it return 25.059999465942383. What is the problem?

I'm already used `DECLARE preLb FLOAT(10,2);` and `DECLARE preLb DOUBLE;` but still same problem.

Comment: if I use double instated of float, it'll be ok? @ user7294900

Comment: it'll be more accurate

Comment: i'm already trying double instated and also try float(10,2). but still not working

Comment: finally it solved by using DOUBLE(10,2) and return type DOUBLE. thanks @  user7294900

Answer (score 0):

Try DOUBLE instead of FLOAT

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `lb2oz`(`lb` DOUBLE) RETURNS double
BEGIN 
    DECLARE preLb DOUBLE; 
    SET preLb = FORMAT(lb,0);
    RETURN preLb+ROUND(((lb - preLb)/16*100), 2);
END
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, already solved